# Tkinter - Keep application visible after lose focus

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to make a window still visible after it has lost focus. An example of what I'm trying to achieve is a window like the windows on-screen keyboard, when you click on another window, it doesn't go ontop of the on-screen keyboard window. Can anyone give me a way to do this in tkinter?

Comment: It's hard to get this kind of "always on top" behavior, because what happens if there are two windows that both want to always be on top? It devolves into a game of [walls and ladders](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/03/10/10138969.aspx) and whoever wins, the user loses.

Comment: Are you happy with a windows-only solution?

Comment: I'm ok with a windows only solution

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking, but doing something like `mytoplevel.attributes("-topmost", True)` should make your window always to be at the top, no matter what you click...